# Installing Ralinl RT3290 wireless driver in Ubuntu Studio 12.10

Tags: wireless, drivers, ralink

I've been using windows since 20 years ago, and now I've decided to try ubuntu, I find that it's impossible to activate the dammed wireless.

I have been following the instructions in different forums to install the driver and there is no way, I'm sick and I am thinking seriously to return to the damned windows: I didn't now Ubuntu was going to be so hard to use, I only want to install a damned driver, does it has to be so complicated???

My last try: I have updated kernel from `3.4` to `3.9`, and returned to install the `rt3290 ralink` driver following this:

```
$git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/dwmw2/linux-firmware.git
$sudo cp linux-firmware/rt3290.bin /lib/firmware
```

and this:

- First, right-click the file and select Rename.
- Rename it to `2012_0508_RT3290_Linux_STA_v2.6.0.0.tar.bz2` ; that is, without the leading slash and adding .tar.
- Now right-click it and select Extract Here. Open the file os/linux/config.mk with any text editor and change the line:

`HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=n`

...to

`HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y`

- Proofread, save and close the text editor.

Now, with a temporary ethernet connection, do:

```
$sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic

$cd Desktop/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508
```

...or wherever you extracted the package, if not your desktop.

```
$sudo su
$make
$make install
$modprobe rt3290sta
$exit
```

---

**NOTE:**

About thee git thing, the system told me that instruction is not installed, exactly the same as make install.

May be there is a bug??? Please help/

Comment: You will need to install linux-headers, build-essential and git.

Comment: Can you post the output of the commands ?